# Is there a command to stop using a database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm refering to when we say `USE dbTest` we start using that database and we can create tables and what not, and if we want to change databases we could just say `USE dbNotatest` and it would change the database we're using.

But is there a way to stop using the database we selected in the first place, without starting to use another one?

Comment: Why do you want that? you need to be using one database to query against

Comment: Yeah, I tried to drop a database I was using and of course I couldn't since I was using it, that's how it ocurred to me, I guess we could always change to master though.

Comment: Do you want to query against no databases???!!

Comment: I wanted to `DROP` it like I said.

Comment: Then `DROP` the database. I don't get it.

Comment: You can't `DROP` the database you're using unless you change databases, didn't you read the question?

Comment: In SSMS if you want to restore a database you cannot restore it if it is 'used' because it is open.   When testing changes on client data I do this dozens of times a day. Thus if there is no 'close' and the ability to keep SSMS open then this is a nutcase design.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To stop using a database, you will need to change your database context.  For example, if you are trying to drop your database and you are in the context of that database, simply switch to another database (commonly `master` or `tempdb`).

If other connections are open to the database and preventing you from dropping the database, you will need to kill the connected spids.  This can be tedious, so an option to force close all connections and then drop your database that usually works for me is:

```
use [master];
ALTER DATABASE [foo] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE [foo] SET ONLINE;
DROP DATABASE [foo];
```

By taking the database offline with rollback immediate, I force all connections closed and rollback any open transactions.  Now, I could drop it while it is offline, but if I do the database files will remain on the file system.  Dropping a database online will remove the database files, so I bring it back online before I drop it.

Comment: FWIW I could set my db offline but then didn't have permissions to set it back online, so I don't recommend this

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in SQL Server.

you can use only use query to manipulate other databasees otherwise you don have any options.

Answer (score 0):

you can detach it just by using another database . for example in Microsoft sql sever management you can use the test database that already exists